# How to convert a video to a long panorama using opencv or any stitcher algorithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, image-stitching

I want to create a linear video into a long panorama either directly into one long panorama or brokeninto many smaller panoramas stacked together. The video looks like this. What is the best approach? I have tried stitching a few frames at a time but im not getting a stitch . Is there a particular approach which is worth heading into? The video is 60 seconds long and can be broken into frames at any fps.
This is my code so far

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import imutils


# DEFINE THE HELPER FUNCTIONS

def draw_matches(img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2, matches):
    r, c = img1.shape[:2]
    r1, c1 = img2.shape[:2]

    # Create a blank image with the size of the first image + second image
    output_img = np.zeros((max([r, r1]), c + c1, 3), dtype='uint8')
    output_img[:r, :c, :] = np.dstack([img1])
    output_img[:r1, c:c + c1, :] = np.dstack([img2])

    # Go over all of the matching points and extract them
    for match in matches:
        img1_idx = match.queryIdx
        img2_idx = match.trainIdx
        (x1, y1) = keypoints1[img1_idx].pt
        (x2, y2) = keypoints2[img2_idx].pt

        # Draw circles on the keypoints
        cv2.circle(output_img, (int(x1), int(y1)), 4, (0, 255, 255), 1)
        cv2.circle(output_img, (int(x2) + c, int(y2)), 4, (0, 255, 255), 1)

        # Connect the same keypoints
        cv2.line(output_img, (int(x1), int(y1)), (int(x2) + c, int(y2)), (0, 255, 255), 1)

    return output_img


def warpImages(img1, img2, H):
    rows1, cols1 = img1.shape[:2]
    rows2, cols2 = img2.shape[:2]

    list_of_points_1 = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, rows1], [cols1, rows1], [cols1, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    temp_points = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, rows2], [cols2, rows2], [cols2, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    # When we have established a homography we need to warp perspective
    # Change field of view
    list_of_points_2 = cv2.perspectiveTransform(temp_points, H)

    list_of_points = np.concatenate((list_of_points_1, list_of_points_2), axis=0)

    [x_min, y_min] = np.int32(list_of_points.min(axis=0).ravel() - 0.5)
    [x_max, y_max] = np.int32(list_of_points.max(axis=0).ravel() + 0.5)

    translation_dist = [-x_min, -y_min]

    H_translation = np.array([[1, 0, translation_dist[0]], [0, 1, translation_dist[1]], [0, 0, 1]])

    output_img = cv2.warpPerspective(img2, H_translation.dot(H), (x_max - x_min, y_max - y_min))
    output_img[translation_dist[1]:rows1 + translation_dist[1], translation_dist[0]:cols1 + translation_dist[0]] = img1
    # print(output_img)

    return output_img

# End of Funcion definitions

# Main program begins here

# Define input and output paths
input_path = "/Users/akshayacharya/Desktop/Panorama/Bazinga/Test images for final/Highfps2fps/*.jpg"

# Define whatever variables necessary

input_img = glob.glob(input_path)
img_path = sorted(input_img)
for i in range(0, len(img_path)):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path[i])
    img = cv2.resize(img, (400, 300))
    cv2.imwrite(img_path[i], img)
tmp = img_path[0]
flag = True
pano = []
i = 1
count = 0
indices = []
k = 1

while i < len(img_path):
    indices.append(i)
    print(i)
    count += 1
    if flag:
        img1 = cv2.imread(tmp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img2 = cv2.imread(img_path[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        flag = False
    img1 = cv2.resize(img1, (0, 0), fx=1, fy=1)
    img2 = cv2.imread(img_path[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (0, 0), fx=1, fy=1)

    orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=2000)

    keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
    keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

    # Create a BFMatcher object.
    # It will find all of the matching keypoints on two images
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher_create(cv2.NORM_HAMMING)

    # Find matching points
    matches = bf.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, k=2)

    all_matches = []
    for m, n in matches:
        all_matches.append(m)

    # Finding the best matches
    good = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.9 * n.distance:
            good.append(m)

    MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 15

    if len(good) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
        # Convert keypoints to an argument for findHomography
        src_pts = np.float32([keypoints1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        dst_pts = np.float32([keypoints2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

        # Establish a homography
        M, _ = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)

        result = warpImages(img2, img1, M)
        img1 = result

    i += 1

    if count % 8 == 0:
        i += 12
        count = 0
        """stitched = img1
        print(np.shape(stitched))
        stitched = cv2.copyMakeBorder(stitched, 10, 10, 10, 10,
                                      cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, (0, 0, 0))

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(stitched, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

        cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

        mask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(mask, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), 255, -1)

        minRect = mask.copy()
        sub = mask.copy()

        while cv2.countNonZero(sub) > 0:
            minRect = cv2.erode(minRect, None)
            sub = cv2.subtract(minRect, thresh)

        cnts = cv2.findContours(minRect.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        
        stitched = stitched[y:y + h, x:x + w]
"""
        #pano.append(stitched)
        result = cv2.resize(result, (1080, 720))

        #cv2.imwrite(f"Test images for final/Highfps2fps/temp_pano/frame{k}.jpg", stitched)
        k += 1
        try:
            img1 = cv2.imread(img_path[i])
            i = i + 1
            img1 = cv2.resize(img1, (400, 300))
            cv2.imshow("Stitch", result)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            indices = []
            print(np.shape(img1))
        except:
            continue
if len(indices) == 8:
    indices = [0]
    j= 100000

if indices[0] != 0:
    i = 0
    print(indices)
    j = indices[i]
    temp = img_path[j]

if j == (len(img_path) - 1):
    img_1 = cv2.imread(temp)
i = 1
flag1 = True
while i < len(indices):
    if flag1:
        img_1 = cv2.imread(temp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        j = indices[i]
        img_2 = cv2.imread(img_path[j], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        flag1 = False
    img_1 = cv2.resize(img1, (0, 0), fx=1, fy=1)
    img_2 = cv2.imread(img_path[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_2 = cv2.resize(img2, (0, 0), fx=1, fy=1)

    orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=2000)

    keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img_1, None)
    keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img_2, None)

    bf = cv2.BFMatcher_create(cv2.NORM_HAMMING)

    matches = bf.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, k=2)

    all_matches = []
    for m, n in matches:
        all_matches.append(m)

    # Finding the best matches
    good = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.9 * n.distance:
            good.append(m)

    MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10

    if len(good) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
        # Convert keypoints to an argument for findHomography
        src_pts = np.float32([keypoints1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        dst_pts = np.float32([keypoints2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

        # Establish a homography
        M, _ = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)

        result1 = warpImages(img_2, img_1, M)
        img_1 = result1

    i += 1
if j != 100000:
    img_1 = cv2.resize(img_1,(400,300))
    #cv2.imwrite(f"Test images for final/Highfps2fps/temp_pano/frame{k}.jpg", img_1)
    cv2.imshow("Last pano", img_1)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

# stacking all the tiny panoramas
input_path = "/Users/akshayacharya/Desktop/Panorama/Bazinga/Test images for final/Highfps2fps/temp_pano/*.jpg"
output_path = "/Users/akshayacharya/Desktop/Panorama/Bazinga/Output/New/pano10.jpg"

list_images = glob.glob(input_path)
list_sorted = sorted(list_images)

images = []
for image in list_sorted:
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (1280, 720))
    # cv2.imshow(f"{image}", img)
    images.append(img)

final_image = cv2.hconcat(images)
#final_image = cv2.resize(final_image, (2000,1500))
cv2.imshow("Acceptable",final_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
#cv2.imwrite(output_path, final_image)
```

Comment: Did you manage to get a output ?